# What is the fastest way to create new model and set properties in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, instantiation

I was wondering which of these two ways to instantiate a class/model, and set properties in C#, is the fastest and uses fewer resources.

Say class `TestClass` has a string property called `Info`.

```
var instantiatedClass = new TestClass();
instantiatedClass.Info = "Information";
```

or

```
var instantiatedClass = new TestClass {
    Info = "Information"
}
```

Of course, I want to know which is the fastest, when you have to set say 10+ properties.
The above was just for illustrating.

Thank you

(Please comment if anything in this post could be better)

Comment: Fastest for what? Reading? The compiler? I believe I read some assembly benchmarking on this on SO a while ago and both were essentially the same (the difference was incredibly small), but in terms of readability I always found using an object initializer was easier to read.

Comment: Don't worry about faster unless you can measure a difference. The second syntax is clearer, so is generally preferable.

Comment: Fastest for setting the property to a new value @JayGould

Comment: So for the compiler? There's essentially no difference.

Comment: The second code you posted can only be used when initializing a new instance of `TestClass`, so you cannot set *"the property to a new value"* with that syntax (you're initializing the value of the property for a new instance of `TestClass`)..

Comment: I understand @bassfader but then 'set a value'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second snippet is just syntactic sugar. Behind the scenes, its all same for a compiler as it generates almost same IL code.

So it does not matter what code is used, end result (in terms of performance) will remain the same.

**First snippet IL code**

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       20 (0x14)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class SO.TestClass instantiatedClass)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void SO.TestClass::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldloc.0
  IL_0008:  ldstr      "Information"
  IL_000d:  callvirt   instance void SO.TestClass::set_Info(string)
  IL_0012:  nop
  IL_0013:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

**Second code snippet IL code**

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       20 (0x14)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] class SO.TestClass instantiatedClass)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void SO.TestClass::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  dup
  IL_0007:  ldstr      "Information"
  IL_000c:  callvirt   instance void SO.TestClass::set_Info(string)
  IL_0011:  nop
  IL_0012:  stloc.0
  IL_0013:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: Allright. That answered my question I guess; it's the same speed. Thanks

Comment: 7 minutes until I can do so.